# Json organization

Tags: python, json

I use JSON for one of my project. For example, I have the JSON structure.

```
{
    "address":{
        "streetAddress": {
                  "aptnumber" : "21",
                  "building_number" : "2nd", 
                  "street" : "Wall Street",
            },
        "city":"New York"
    },
    "phoneNumber":
    [
        {
            "type":"home",
            "number":"212 555-1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I have a bunch of modules using this structure, and it expects to see certain fields in the received json. For the example above, I have two files: address_manager and phone_number_manager. Each will be passed the relevant information. So address_manager will expect a dict that has keys 'streetAddress' and 'city'.

My question is: Is it possible to set up a constant structure so that every time I change the name of a field in my JSON structure (e.g. I want to change 'streetAddress' to 'address'), I don't have to make change in several places?

My naive approach is to have a bunch of constants (e.g. 
`ADDRESS = "address"
 ADDRESS_STREET_ADDRESS = "streetAddress"`
..etc..
) and so if I want to change the name of one of my fields in JSON structure, I just have to make change in one place. However, this seems to be very inefficient because my constant naming would be terribly long once I reach the third or fourth layer of the JSON structure (e.g. ADDRESS_STREETADDRESS_APTNUMBER, ADDRESS_STREETADDRESS_BUILDINGNUMBER)

I am doing this in python, but any generic answer would be OK.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do your constant names have to include all the levels of your JSON structure? Just call one APT_NUMBER corresponding to address->streetAddress->aptnumber, unless there is somewhere else that aptnumber can occur?

Comment: Why don't you not change the names of the fields?

Comment: If you change `streetAddress` to `address`, wouldn't you then want to change `ADDRESS_STREET_ADDRESS` to `ADDRESS_ADDRESS`? And then you'd have to change it everywhere that constant is used... Doesn't seem like much of a time saver.

Comment: OK, so I don't need the whole layers above for constant name, now I still have a bunch of constant: ADDRESS, STREET_ADDRESS, CITY, APT_NUMBER, STREET ... Would that still be hard to maintain? Is there a way to organize this? Like using a schema where I can directly query the name of a field in a JSON structure?

Comment: This is the purpose of something like the header file of C or C++. Just have a single file and use import in you python structure. That way you do not need to change anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Cameron Sparr suggested in a comment, don't have your constant names include all levels of your JSON structure. If you have the same data in multiple places, it will actually be *better* if you reuse the same constant. For example, suppose your JSON has a phone number included in the address:

```
{
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": {
            "aptnumber" : "21",
            "building_number" : "2nd", 
            "street" : "Wall Street"
        },
        "city":"New York",
        "phoneNumber":
        [
            {
                "type":"home",
                "number":"212 555-1234"
            }
        ]
    },
    "phoneNumber":
    [
        {
            "type":"home",
            "number":"212 555-1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why not have a single constant `PHONES = 'phoneNumber'` that you use in both places? Your constants will have shorter names, and it is more logically coherent. You would end up using it like this (assuming JSON is stored in `person`):

```
person[ADDRESS][PHONES][x] # Phone numbers associated with that address
person[PHONES][x] # Phone numbers associated with the person
```

Instead of

```
person[ADDRESS][ADDRESS_PHONES][x]
person[PHONE_NUMBERS][x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script than when you change the constant, change the structure in all json files.

Example:

```
import json
CHANGE = ('steet', 'streetAddress')
json_data = None
with open('file.json') as jfile:
    json_data = jfile.load(jfile)
    json_data[CHANGE[1]], json_data[CHANGE[0]] = json_data[CHANGE[0]], None
```

Comment: This changes the data in the JSON file. He is asking about changing the key in his code.